# Esta pagina no funciona a la hora de destruir la sesion

Tags: php

estoy intentando destruir la sesion de una cuenta pero a la hora de cerrarla me da error en el buscador

codigo html 
a la hora de poner la condicional es donde me esta arrojando el error, intente colocar la condicional en el controlador del login, me hace el cierre de sesion pero no la destruye es decir que se puede devolver

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if(($_SESSION['Operario'])!=''){
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE Html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Inicio Sesion</title>
            <link type="text/css" href="assets/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <body>
              <form name="loginform" id="loginform" method="POST" action="controllers/controllers_login.php">
                <div id=tituloG>
                    <h1> Liceo Juan Ramón Jiménez </h1>
                </div
                <div id="subtitulo"><h2>Inicio sesión</h2></div>
                <?php
            if(isset($_GET["fallo"]) && $_GET["fallo"] == 'true')
            {
               echo "<center><div style='color:red'>Usuario o Contraseña Incorrectos </div></center>";
            }
          ?>
                </div> <br>
                      <div id="contenedor">
                                 <div id="inputs">
                           <label id="ingresar">Ingrese su Usuario:</label>
                            <input name ="correo" type="text" id="correo" placeholder="Correo Institucional"autofocus required >
                            <label id="ingresar">Ingrese su Contraseña:</label>
                            <input  name="contrasenia" type="password" id="contrasenia" placeholder="Contraseña"autofocus required >
                                  </div>
                                  <div id="btn">
                                <input type="submit" name="submiti" id="submiti" value="Iniciar Sesión" >
                                  </div>
                          <div id="pie">
                              <a id="pie" href="#">Si olvidó su usuario o contraseña por favor comuniquese con el administrador </a>
                                </div>
                                </div>
            </form>
          </body>
        </head>
    </html>
    <?php
    }else{
    //  echo"necesita volver a iniciar sesion";
    header("Location: index.php");
    }
     ?>
```

codigo php de logout

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header("Location: ../index.php");

 ?>
```

[image: error en el buscador]

Comment: Por lo que veo, ahí mismo creaste un bucle en donde nunca inicias sesión, está siempre redireccionando a index.php, para redireccionar correctamente deberías enviar a login.php.

Comment: Te digo lo mismo que @harifo, tienes una redirección infinita, si tu condición `(isset($_GET["fallo"]) && $_GET["fallo"] == 'true')` no se cumple en tu primera página, que aunque no lo indicas supongo que es tu index.php se redirecciona a si misma una y otra vez.

Comment: mi index es el login donde esta toda la parte de interfaz grafica, querras decir que lo suba donde se realiza el codigo php ? ya intente esa opcion y me redirecciona bien, pero no me destruye la sesion